# If $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $(A-I)^2=0$, then what is $det(2I-A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $(A-I)^2=0$, then what is $det(2I-A)$?

We can write $A=J^{-1}DJ$ and thus $(D-I)^2=0$. Therefore the diagonal entries of $D-I$ should all be zero. Hence, $det(A)=det(D)=1$.

But how to calculate $det(2I-A)$? Is it true here that $det(2I-A)=det(2I)-det(A)$?

Comment: $A$ need not be diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(A-I)^2=A^2-2A+I=0$ implies $I=2A-A^2$ and $I=A(2I-A)$, $det(A)(det(2I-A))=1$ and $det(2I-A)={1\over{det(A)}}=1$.

Comment: And since the only eigenvalue is $1$, ....

Comment: As for $det(mI-A)$, how can we generalize this approach?

Comment: Consider $(A-{m\over 2}I)^2=0$, it implies $A^2-mA+{m^2\over 4}I=0$, you deduce that $A(mI-A)={m^2\over 4}$ and $det(mI-A)={m^2\over{4det(A)}}$. Use the fact that $det(A)=m^n$ to conclude.

Comment: Why $(A-\frac{m}{2}I)^2=0$? Also, shouldn't $det(A)=1$?

Comment: It is the hypothesis like $(A-I)^2=0$

Comment: Oh I mean under the same hypothesis $(A-I)^2=0$, how to find $det(mI-A)$. Sorry for not clarifying this.

Comment: I used the hypothesis $(A-(m/2)I)^2 =0$ instead.